# How do you make some bot commands only work in some discord channels

Tags: discord, discord.js

This is my first time using js. I need to ban a certain word in a certain channel. I don't want the message to be deleted if it is not in the specific channel.

For Example:

I want to ban the word "goodbye" in the #greeting channel
BUT
I don't want to ban the word "goodbye" In the #farewell channel

How would I go about this?

Thanks.
By the way I wanted to use example code, but none of it made any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a simple example for you on how to achieve this:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const Client = new Discord.Client();

const ForbiddenWords = {
    "ChannelID": ["goodbaye", "bye"] // Greeting channel
};

Client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log(`${Client.user.tag} is ready!`);
});

Client.on("message", (message) => { // Fired when the bot detects a new message.
    if (message.author.bot) {return false}; // Checking if the message author is a bot.
    if (ForbiddenWords[message.channel.id]) { // Checking if the current channel has any forbidden words in the ForbiddenWords Object
        if (ForbiddenWords[message.channel.id].some(word => message.content.toString().toLowerCase().includes(word))) { // Checking if the message contains any forbidden words
             message.delete(); // Deleting the message.
        };
    };
});

Client.login(process.env.DISCORD_AUTH_TOKEN);
```